# detect communities using networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I have a database that look like this:

| id_1 | id_2 | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| H4FR923 | AAE9987Y | 01-01-2018 |

I have read the data as this way:

```
    import pandas as pd 
    
    path = "data.csv"
    
    df = pd.read_csv(path)
```

and then create a network using netowkrx by doing this way:

```
    import networkx as nx 
    G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='id_1', target='id_2', edge_attr='date')
```

Now i want to detect communities, i need to define communities based on dates. for example like we have under the columns dates this date:
1-1-2018 - 1-6-2018

i want to build a community that hold all the nodes between this dates 1-1-2018 tp 1-6-2018 and community_2 could have 2-6-2018 to 30-12-2018 something like this

so each community should have the nodes that have a set of dates

is that possible!!

here is what i did:

```
from networkx.algorithms import community

partition = community.asyn_lpa_communities(G) 

def modularity(G, partition):
W = sum(G.edges[v, w].get('weight', 1) for v, w in G.edges)
summation = 0
for cluster_nodes in partition:
    s_c = sum(G.degree(n, weight='weight') for n in cluster_nodes)
    # Use subgraph to count only internal links
    C = G.subgraph(cluster_nodes)
    W_c = sum(C.edges[v, w].get('weight', 1) for v, w in C.edges)
    summation += W_c - s_c ** 2 / (4 * W)

return summation / W
```

but now sure how to do the communities based on i described above any help please!!

Comment: I'm not sure how would you partition the vertices based on edge attributes.  "Communities are often defined in terms of the partition of the set of vertices, that is each node is put into one and only one community.." [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_structure) . If each node holds it's own date attribute then things are pretty simple, you just assign a partition attribute to each node based on the date attribute, but with edges holding the information, each node may refer to multiple dates.

Comment: Yes that what i was thinking is there is an easy way to give attributes to the nodes rather than G.nodes[node]['date']= '01-01-2018'. In this way i will give attributes to every node in the dataset and that's a lot is there is an easuer way to do that!?

Comment: What you are asking in the comment isn't part of the question you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed you want to partition `id_1` nodes based on the `date` in the edges dataframe.

Based on the specifications you gave on your comment I believe you want something like this:

```python
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "id_1": [1, 2, 3],
    "id_2": [2, 3, 1],
    "date": ["date1", "date2", "date1"],
}


df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[x for x in data.keys()])

# df =
#    id_1  id_2   date
# 0     1     2  date1
# 1     2     3  date2
# 2     3     1  date1

node_attrs = dict(zip(df.id_1, df.date))

# node_attrs ={1: 'date1', 2: 'date2', 3: 'date1'}

for node in node_attrs:
    node_attrs[node] = {"date": node_attrs[node]}

for node in node_attrs:
    if node_attrs[node]["date"] == "date1":
        node_attrs[node]["partition"] = 1
    else:
        node_attrs[node]["partition"] = 2


# creating the graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source="id_1", target="id_2")

nx.set_node_attributes(G, node_attrs)

print(G.nodes(data=True))

# output: [(1, {'date': 'date1', 'partition': 1}), (2, {'date': 'date2', 'partition': 2}), (3, {'date': 'date1', 'partition': 1})]
```

All nodes are partitioned based on their `date` attribute.

Comment: ok if i want to give attributes to all id_1 and id_2 and when we call nx.set_node_attributes(G, node_attrs) it only give for id_1 right!!